# Kendo UI dataSource get set using javascript object

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui

Just started experimenting with Kendo UI and I'm stuck with how one can use a standard javascript object to use as the datasource.

It's easy enough to initially load the data from the javascript object but I want to be able to get the data back after changes have occurred through user interaction.

Preferably, if this object is somehow synced with the widget, so all one has to do is read/write to this javascript object.

Our data:

```
var _data = [
{
    eventID: 8,
    title: "Group meeting.",
    start: new Date("2013/06/13 07:00"),
    end: new Date("2013/06/13 08:30"),
    pending:false,
    recurrenceRule: "",
    recurrenceException: "",
    description: "Take my brother to his group meeting.",
    isAllDay:false,
    ownTimeSlot:true,
    careAssistantId: 5,
    clientId: 6
},{
    eventID: 9,
    title: "Make dinner.",
    start: new Date("2013/06/13 11:00"),
    end: new Date("2013/06/13 13:30"),
    pending:true,
    recurrenceRule: "",
    recurrenceException: "",
    description: "Make dinner for my mom.",
    isAllDay:false,
    ownTimeSlot:true,
    careAssistantId: 5,
    clientId: 6
} ];
```

Init widget:

```
function save(){
   console.log(_data);    
}

$('.schedule').kendoScheduler({
        date: new Date("2013/6/13"),
        startTime: new Date("2013/6/13 07:00 AM"),
        height: 600,
        views: [ { type: "week", selected: true }],
        save: save,
        dataSource:_data
});
```

Here is the code setup to be tested (note the console.log debug on save):

http://jsfiddle.net/t23Ce/11/

How is one supposed to read/write the 'state' in the Kendo UI world?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A simple array cannot provide change tracking, so it is converted to a [DataSource](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/framework/datasource) when you create your widget. You can access the current state of your data in various ways:

1. get an array to iterate over [all data](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/framework/datasource#methods-data): `dataSource.data()`
2. access a [specific item](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/framework/datasource#methods-at): `dataSource.at(1)`
3. get [filtered data](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/framework/datasource#methods-view): `datasource.view()`
4. get a [pure JS array](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/framework/observablearray#methods-toJSON) back: `dataSource.data().toJSON()`

Comment: The "dataSource.data().toJSON()" works perfectly. The only issue I'm seeing is when I delete and get a 'remove' event I still see the event in the dataSource...

Comment: @zaf I don't understand the problem - can you update your fiddle to illustrate it?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/NZ4EM/9/  I see that it probably removes the event AFTER the function call because if you delete both you'll notice the debug decrease by one.

Comment: @zac I see what you mean - the remove event is triggered before removing the element so that you can prevent the removal using e.preventDefault(); if you want to track changes, you can use the DataSource change event instead (or you could implement your own afterRemove event for scheduler)

Comment: @zaf I was talking about the change event of the data source; see [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lhoeppner/NZ4EM/13/)

Comment: Thanks for all that. I think I can move along now.

Comment: dataSource.at(n) returns the nth in the dataSource. You can also access a specific item by its id with dataSource.get(myId).

Answer (score 2):

Despite you initialize the `dataSource` from a JavaScript array (`_data`), KendoUI internally creates a DataSource (in your case a `SchedulerDataSource`) that only uses your array for loading the initial content.

If you need / want to keep using the array and reflect the changes in it, you would probably need to write some code for updating it.

If you can live with `_data` defined as a `ShedulerDataSource`, then you can try defining it as:

```
var _data = new kendo.data.SchedulerDataSource({
    data: [    {
        eventID: 8,
        title: "Group meeting.",
        start: new Date("2013/06/13 07:00"),
        end: new Date("2013/06/13 08:30"),
        pending:false,
        recurrenceRule: "",
        recurrenceException: "",
        description: "Take my brother to his group meeting.",
        isAllDay:false,
        ownTimeSlot:true,
        careAssistantId: 5,
        clientId: 6
    },{
        eventID: 9,
        title: "Make dinner.",
        start: new Date("2013/06/13 11:00"),
        end: new Date("2013/06/13 13:30"),
        pending:true,
        recurrenceRule: "",
        recurrenceException: "",
        description: "Make dinner for my mom.",
        isAllDay:false,
        ownTimeSlot:true,
        careAssistantId: 5,
        clientId: 6
    } ],
    schema: {
        model : {
            id : "eventID"
        }
    }
});
```

See it running here : http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/t23Ce/14/

Comment: Thanks for that. I see that the _data object gets updated and I could iterate over the '_data' object within that and then json encode and decode to finally get something that resembles the original input data structure. It's probably me but that sure looks like jumping through several hoops to get to the data. There must be  some magic method somewhere…

Comment: @zaf - if you need to get a "pure" JavaScript array of the data in the DataSource, you can do that too - I updated my answer

Comment: @zaf, getting the data as JavaScript -for reading- is as easy as doing `_data.data()` but you should not update this array since changes will not be reflected in the UI.